# Spray routing doesn't work

Tags: scala, routes, spray

Can anyone explain why this example only reacts to: localhost:8080?

```
package com.example

import akka.actor.Actor
import spray.routing._
import spray.http._
import MediaTypes._

// we don't implement our route structure directly in the service actor because
// we want to be able to test it independently, without having to spin up an actor
class MyServiceActor extends Actor with MyService {

  // the HttpService trait defines only one abstract member, which
  // connects the services environment to the enclosing actor or test
  def actorRefFactory = context

  // this actor only runs our route, but you could add
  // other things here, like request stream processing
  // or timeout handling
  def receive = runRoute(myRoute)
}


// this trait defines our service behavior independently from the service actor
trait MyService extends HttpService {

  val myRoute =
    path("test1") {
      get {
        respondWithMediaType(`text/html`) { // XML is marshalled to `text/xml` by default, so we simply override here
          complete {
            <html>
              <body>
                <h1>test1</h1>
              </body>
            </html>
          }
        }
      }
    } ~
    path("test2") {
      get {
        respondWithMediaType(`text/html`) { // XML is marshalled to `text/xml` by default, so we simply override here
          complete {
            <html>
              <body>
                <h1>TEST SPRAY</h1>
              </body>
            </html>
          }
        }
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: How does it 'react'? What are you expecting that is not happening? How do you actually use your `MyServiceActor` and open you server socket?

Comment: I expect to get on my browser: "test1" response for "localhost:8080/test1" and "test2" for "localhost:8080/test2". Instead I get only "test1" for "localhost:8080/"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know how you start your server, but this code gives me exactly what you expect test1 for localhost:8080/test1 and TEST SPRAY for test2

```
object MyServiceServer extends App {

  implicit val system = ActorSystem("my-service")

  val service = system.actorOf(Props[MyServiceActor], "my-service")


  IO(Http) ! Http.Bind(service, "localhost", 8080)
}
```

Comment: This is strange. After restarting intelliJ it got fixed. I was sure Spray should automatically refresh the page. It also didn't work after <ctrl>+<shift>+<F9> and restarting the server.

Comment: You may want to try spray revolver plugin for sbt for faster redeployment and dev lifecycle

Comment: Thanks. I do use it, but it seems like it doesn't work for some reason... Nothing never works out-of-the-box on intelliJ...